# JMeter XPath getting multiple values and odd output order

Tags: xpath, jmeter

### Preamble

I have a JMeter script with an XPath Extractor, in this I have specified a query that gets multiple values from the XML document. This all works fine

[image: XPath Extractor]

#### XML

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<InventoryAvailabilityAdvice>
  <Warehouse>WFC2</Warehouse>
  <Timestamp>2019-07-31T23:00:02.177</Timestamp>
  <InventoryItem>
    <ItemNumber>80903</ItemNumber>
    <AvailableQuantity UnitOfMeasure="EA">13</AvailableQuantity>
  </InventoryItem>
  <InventoryItem>
    <ItemNumber>80901</ItemNumber>
    <AvailableQuantity UnitOfMeasure="EA">17</AvailableQuantity>
  </InventoryItem>
</InventoryAvailabilityAdvice>
```

### Problem

When I then try to get these values in a loop using a JSR232 Sampler they don't seem to come out in the order declared in the XPath Query.
[image: JSR232 Code and log output]

I expected theData_2 to contain the UnitOfMeasure attribute and theData_3 to contain the quantity, but as you can see they are reversed.

### Question

Is this expected behavior? If so, when an element has multiple attributes how do I know which order those will be made available as?

Thanks

Comment: As per my understanding here is the order xpath path executed `root >element >text >attribute`

Comment: I strongly suspect this is expected behavior. The XPath union operator ("|") is defined to yield a sequence of nodes in document order. Since element nodes precede their attributes in document order, you're seeing the values of the `AvailableQuantity` elements themselves before the values of their `UnitOfMeasure` attributes. You might try something like `//InventoryItem/(string(ItemNumber), string(AvailableQuantity/@UnitOfMeasure), string(AvailableQuantity))`, assuming XPath 2.0 is available. Note that this expression is no longer selecting nodes, just a sequence of string values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of XPath nodesets produced by union operator is not guaranteed, you can see [`putValuesForXPathInList()`](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/v5_1_1/src/core/org/apache/jmeter/util/XPathUtil.java#L363) function for implementation details

Actually if you've decided to go for Groovy - you don't even need the [XPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor), you can use [XmlSlurper](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/XmlSlurper.html) class for parsing the XML response.

Example code:

```
def response = new XmlSlurper().parseText(prev.getResponseDataAsString())

response.InventoryItem.eachWithIndex { item, index ->
    log.info('Item: ' + index)
    log.info('ItemNumber: ' + item.ItemNumber)
    log.info('AvailableQuantiry: ' + item.AvailableQuantity)
    log.info('UnitOfMeasure:' + item.AvailableQuantity.@UnitOfMeasure)
}
```

Demo:

[image]

References:

- [Groovy: Processing XML](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)

Comment: Thank you, this helped. The actual test will be using the variables in a HTTP request the Groovy code was just to see/show what was happening.